# VB.NET encoding one character wrong

Tags: vb.net, encoding, binary, arrays

I have a byte array that I'm encoding to a string:

```
Private Function GetKey() As String
    Dim ba() As Byte = {&H47, &H43, &H44, &H53, &H79, &H73, &H74, &H65, &H6D, _
                        &H73, &H89, &HA, &H1, &H32, &H31, &H36}

    Dim strReturn As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ba)

    Return strReturn
End Function
```

Then I write that to a file via IO.File.AppendAllText.
If I open that file in 010 Editor (to view the binary data) it displays as this:

47 43 44 53 79 73 74 65 6D 73 **3F** 0A 01 32 31 36

The original byte array contained **89** at position 11, and the encoded string contains **3F**.
If I change my encoding to Encoding.Default.GetString, it gives me:

47 43 44 53 79 73 74 65 6D 73 **E2 80 B0** 0A 01 32 31 36

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Encoding.ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx) is limited to 7-bit characters. That is byte values from 0 to 127 (&H00 to &H7F). GetString sets all values outside this range to &H3F which is a questionmark.

[Encoding.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx) is the current ANSI code page for the operating system which on my computer is CodePage 1252..

> The ANSI code pages can be different
>   on different computers, or can be
>   changed for a single computer, leading
>   to data corruption. For the most
>   consistent results, applications
>   should use Unicode, such as UTF-8
>   (code page 65001) or UTF-16, instead
>   of a specific code page.

[Encoding.UTF7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf7.aspx) would work for you here:

```
Dim strReturn As String = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(ba)
```

**Edit:**

Instead of using Encoding I'd write the bytes directly using something like this:

```
Dim key = GetKey()
Dim f = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("output.txt")
f.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)
f.Write(key, 0, key.Length)
f.Close()

Private Function GetKey() As String
  Dim ba() As Byte = {&H47, &H43, &H44, &H53, &H79, &H73, &H74, &H65, &H6D, &H73, &H89, &HA, &H1, &H32, &H31, &H36}

  Return ba
End Function
```

Comment: This gives me 
47 43 44 53 79 73 74 65 6D 73 C2 89 0A 01 32 31 36

Which has the 89, but also inserted a C2.
I probably need to educate myself on encoding more.

Comment: Hmm... When writing it to the file with AppendAllText then it indeed adds C2. But why do you want to first convert the bytes to a string then write the string to a file? Why not write the bytes directly?

Comment: I need the option of running the string through an encryption function before actually writing it to the file. Sometimes it will be encrypted, sometimes not. I COULD just remove the inserted C2 character after encoding it...

Comment: When encrypting you usually encrypt at byte level, not at string level so I'd still write the bytes themselves instead of the string.